# How Do I Check If A Service Exists And If So Execute A Command With CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-services

I want to execute the following command if a `windows-service` does exist:

```
myservice.exe uninstall
```

Where `myservice` is the name of my windows service.

I have tried:

```
  $serviceName = 'simpleservice'

    If (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        If ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running') {
            Stop-Service $serviceName
            Write-Host "Stopping $serviceName"
        } Else {
            Write-Host "$serviceName found, but it is not running."
        }
    path\to\my\service\$serviceName uninstall
    } Else {
       Write-Host "$serviceName not found"
    }
```

Comment: What language is this? please add the related [tag](https://superuser.com/tags)!

Comment: Whatever you want to do with CMD can be done with PowerShell.... PowerShell replaces CMD and is significantly more powerful and feature rich. You've copied your sample code from the following MS TechNet question: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8c2c8111-8995-4ff6-a25c-e0f48136e14f/determine-if-service-exists?forum=winserverpowershell. You just need to work out how you're going to remove the service, of which there are multiple methods....